# Confusing behavior from a custom unity Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Hello first of all im new to shader programming in unity so if im being stupid im sorry but im rather confused, ive written a custom shader to render light coming from a quad/screen (i am trying to make a cinema type project and want the screen to cast light into the scene) and im having mostly success with this but ive noticed something i found strange, here is the shader first:

```
Shader "Unlit/LightingCustom"
{
    Properties
    {
        // Define the rectangle's properties
        _ScreenCenter("Screen Center", Vector) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        _ScreenNormal("Screen Normal", Vector) = (0, -1, 0, 0)
        _ScreenWidth("Screen Width", Float) = 2.0
        _ScreenHeight("Screen Height", Float) = 1.0

        // Define light properties
        _LightColor ("Light Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        _LightIntensity("Light Intensity", Float) = 1
        _LightAngle("Light Angle", Range(0, 1)) = 0

    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 normal : TEXCOORD1;
                float distance : TEXCOORD2;
                float3 DirectionToLight : TEXCOORD3;
                float3 DirectionToLightYMax : TEXCOORD4;
                float3 DirectionToSurface : TEXCOORD5;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            float4 _ScreenCenter;
            float4 _ScreenNormal;
            float _ScreenWidth;
            float _ScreenHeight;

            float4 _LightColor;
            float _LightIntensity;
            float _LightAngle;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;

                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.normal = normalize(mul((float3x3)unity_WorldToObject, v.normal));
                o.uv = v.uv;

                // Get vertex cood in world space
                float3 worldVertex = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;

                // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // //

                // Get nearest point on the screen rect to the vertex point
                float3 toPoint = worldVertex - _ScreenCenter.xyz;

                // Project the point onto the rectangle's plane
                float distanceAlongNormal = dot(toPoint, normalize(_ScreenNormal.xyz));
                float3 projectedPoint = worldVertex - distanceAlongNormal * normalize(_ScreenNormal.xyz);

                // Calculate the point in the local coordinate system of the rectangle
                float3 localPoint = projectedPoint - _ScreenCenter.xyz;

                // Clamp the coordinates to find the point within the rectangle
                float clampedX = clamp(localPoint.x, -_ScreenWidth * 0.5, _ScreenWidth * 0.5);
                float clampedZ = clamp(localPoint.z, -_ScreenHeight * 0.5, _ScreenHeight * 0.5);

                // Construct the final nearest point in world space
                float3 nearestPoint = _ScreenCenter.xyz + float3(clampedX, 0.0, clampedZ);

                // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // //

                // Calculate direction vectors
                o.DirectionToLight = normalize(nearestPoint - worldVertex);
                o.DirectionToLightYMax = normalize(float3(nearestPoint.x, _ScreenCenter.y + _ScreenHeight * 0.5, nearestPoint.z) - worldVertex);
                o.DirectionToSurface = normalize(worldVertex - nearestPoint);

                // Calculate distance to the screen
                o.distance = length(_ScreenCenter.xyz - worldVertex);

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Diffuse lighting for each pixel
                float DistanceIntensity = 1.0 / pow(i.distance, 2); // Calculate distance intensity

                float AngleIntensityBase = max(0.0, dot(i.normal, i.DirectionToLight)); // Calculate angle intensity for closest point
                float AngleIntensityMax = max(0.0, dot(i.normal, i.DirectionToLightYMax)); // Calculate angle intensity for highest point

                float AngleIntensity = max(AngleIntensityBase, AngleIntensityMax); // Select largest value so screen lights objects below it

                // Check if light is facing the surface pixel
                bool lightFacing = dot(i.DirectionToSurface, normalize(_ScreenNormal)) < -_LightAngle;
                //float lightFacing = max(0.0, dot(normalize(_ScreenNormal.xyz), i.DirectionToSurface)) > _LightAngle ? 1 : 0;

                // Calculate overall intensity
                float intensity = min(1, _LightIntensity * DistanceIntensity * AngleIntensity * lightFacing);

                // Assign pixel color
                fixed4 col = _LightColor * intensity;

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

now the thing that confuses me is that i have this line meant to check whether the pixel being rendered is in front of the screen and so should receive lighting

```
bool lightFacing = dot(i.DirectionToSurface, normalize(_ScreenNormal)) < -_LightAngle;
```

i thought that when taking the dot product of 2 normal vectors the result is a range from 1 to -1 with 1 meaning the normal's are aligned so i believed that i would have to do `dot() > _LightAngle` not `dot() < -LightAngle` but when i do it the way i thought was correct only pixels behind the screen are rendered. this has me stumped obviously my code works as intended im just not sure why, i could have just missed something simple or im stupid idk, im only asking as i want to understand shaders better and this has thrown me off. any thoughts are appreciated :)

i have tried messing round with the code normalizing things switching things around but nothing seems to work and im just very confused as to why it seems like the output of `dot(i.DirectionToSurface, normalize(_ScreenNormal))` is reversed and im not completely sure if the 2 are related but im having other issues and i figure this might be part of the reason why.

Comment: Sorry not to answer the question directly (I don't know the answer) but from a practical point of view maybe a shader is overkill conpared to e.g. an area light or projector light? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lighting.html / https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html. See also https://forum.unity.com/threads/video-light-emission.1038721/

Comment: Seems like a better approach how ever from what i can see this is a costly method and im trying to get this running on a quest 3 so i can have a screen cast light into my real world using mixed reality and as area lights need baking that isn't the best for a screen that can move so i thought that a custom shader would be a more efficient method and i could get some shader programming experience from it although i feel like i may have aimed to high for my second ever shader either way thanks for the advice

Comment: Sorry, you're quite right about the area light. Good luck with the shader, maybe also ask on the Unity forums, GameDev.StackExchange and the ShaderToy community if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Thanks man to be fair right now ive managed to get rid of all my little bugs that where in the code and none of them ended up being connected to the problem in this post so i can just leave it be considering it functions properly, but ill maybe try asking in those places just to clear up my confusion